# maven build issue , error in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am getting this error while building eclipse in pom.xml

I am sharing the full stacktrace:

```
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.editor
> was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:178)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:349)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:265)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:63)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:303)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:94)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
>   at
> org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:694)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:387)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1134)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3210)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3056)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)  at
> org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)    at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:229)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:853)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)    at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)    at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:850)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1142)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1249)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)     at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)    at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)  at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectChangedListener     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:285)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)    at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
>   ... 114 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error
> occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core
> (807).    at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)    at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)     at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)    at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1325)  at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)  at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)    at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3294)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3270)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2883)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1937)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3247)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1962)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.getRawClasspathEntry(PackageFragmentRoot.java:556)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.internalGetParent(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:390)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.processDelta(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:728)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.handleAffectedChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:809)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.processDelta(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:752)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.handleAffectedChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:809)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.processDelta(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:752)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.elementChanged(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:124)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor$4.run(DeltaProcessor.java:1695)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.notifyListeners(DeltaProcessor.java:1685)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.firePostChangeDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:1519)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fire(DeltaProcessor.java:1495)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:770)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:789)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.becomeWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:99)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1001)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1244)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4233)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1480)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2584)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2557)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1395)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2099)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:390)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:305)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1250)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:100)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:678)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:547)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:531)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:69)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>   at
```

Please find the solution.

Comment: are you building eclipse, or with eclipse? That stack trace is good but it would be helpful if you could provide some context around what you are doing

Comment: From the first line in the stack trace it looks more like a problem with Eclipse than with Maven. Try running the build as a maven command on the console, to figure out if it is a Maven issue or an Eclipse issue and provide more context to your question.